# Django URL conf error

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I have the following message when I try to use reverse or reverse_lazy:

> The included URLconf 'ph.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in
>   it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably
>   caused by a circular import

*When I use the urls (without using reverse or reverse lazy) is working with no issue. I tried different combination of urls the same results*

What I'm doing wrong ?

ph is the project. In the project I include the urls for the application:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^account/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^companies/', include('companies.urls', namespace='companies')),
    url(r'^products/', include('products.urls', namespace='products')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

]

# debug toolbar
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ]
```

The app involved:

1)accounts:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import AccountDetailView

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'$', AccountDetailView.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
```

2) products:

```
class ProductCreateView(AccountMixin, CreateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductModelForm
    url = reverse_lazy('accounts:dashboard')
    url2 = reverse_lazy('products:list')
    #print(url)
    template_name = 'accounts/product_form.html'
    #success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:product_detail')
```

Comment: Please show the full ph urls file.

Comment: @DanielRoseman updated

Comment: Using `success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:product_detail')` should be fine. However, you shouldn't print the result, or use `reverse` when defining your class based view, otherwise Django will try to reverse the URL before the URL config has loaded.

Comment: you are correct regarding print().

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem;

I used get_success_url() calling reverse() inside.

reverse_lazy didn't work because it was necessary to pass kwargs for url, and I forgot about that.

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('accounts:product_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})